# AWS StepFunction Choice state price

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

As I know AWS StepFunction standard version is priced by number of state transitions. I couldn't clarify if Choice state execution is also considered as state transition. Basically my question is, does adding Choice state to the Step Function definition will add additional costs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Choice states also result in state transitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me post my problem here so that maybe you can help. I have StepFunction with 15 different steps. To make it cost effective, I want to check if the particular step needs to be executed. If it's not needed, then I want to skip execution of the step and therefore decrease the execution costs. 
I was trying to do that by Choice state but it doesn't make sense as its adding an additional costs anyways. Now I'm wondering if is there some better way to achieve cost effectiveness for the execution. Do you have any idea about it?